# error when opening “An error was encountered while saving the command history”

Tags: 12.04, matlab

I installed matlab on my linux machine but on a media drive `/media/d/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b` but when I open Matlab I get the below error, so if anyone could please advise how to solve this:

```
An error was encountered while saving the command history
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/userA/.matlab/R2014b/History.xml (Permission denied)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.mathworks.mde.cmdhist.AltHistoryCollection$CommandSaver.run(AltHistoryCollection.java:1212)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change permissions of the directory ~/.matlab so that you may write into it. Use following commands in terminal and the problem should be resolved:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 .matlab
```

Comment: Does it really need to be world-writeable? isn't it more likely to be an ownership issue (e.g. as a result of previously running matlab with sudo)?

Comment: yes he can also use chown command, anyway it solves the problem, it is a personal system and shouldnt matter